# Why calling non const function from in body of const function c++?

Tags: c++, constants

Consider the following code, in this case output is:

> f non const
>   g const

It is a bit confusing because someClass is calling non const function for const data member from its const function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Inner
{
public:
    void f() const { cout<< "f const" <<endl; }
    void f() { cout<< "f non const" <<endl; }
};

class someClass
{
    Inner * const obj2;
public:
    someClass():obj2(){}
    void g() {obj2->f(); cout<< "g non const" <<endl; }
    void g() const {obj2->f(); cout<< "g const" <<endl; }

};

int main()
{
    const someClass a;
    a.g();
}
```

Why is someClass calling non const function in this case?

Comment: Because `*obj2` is not const.

Comment: You should at least post the output of this program.

Comment: the output is mentioned in the question

Comment: Ah OK, I improved the formatting to make it stand out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

obj2 in class someClass is a type of Inner * const, which means that the pointer is const, not the data itself, thus it is calling a non const function.

To get the expected output, the obj2 must be declared in this way:

```
Inner const * obj2;
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess you're asking why `void Inner::f()` is called. This is because you have a `const` pointer to non-const `Inner`:

```
Inner * const obj2;
```

If you want a pointer to `const Inner`, then you need

```
const Inner * obj2;
```

or

```
Inner const * obj2;
```

and if you want a `const` pointer to `const` inner,

```
const Inner * const obj2;
```

and I'll let you figure out the other alternative.